# Using variables inside php function

Tags: php, database, function, variables

trying to make my website a bit tidier and simpler to maintain so am trying to move alot of repeated code into functions.

I have a function that takes an argument for an ID, runs a database check using this ID in the where claus and then sets a new variable for the rowCount returned.

However it keeps returning 0 / nothing.

I have made a simple example of what im doing:

```
$buildID = 5;

function select_All_Comments_From_ID($buildID){
    $idNew = $buildID;
        global $idNew
}

select_All_Comments_From_ID($buildID);

echo $idNew;
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Here is what it actually looks like:

```
function select_All_Comments_From_ID($buildID){
    $query = " SELECT * FROM comments WHERE buildID = :buildID"; 
    $query_params = array(':buildID' => $buildID); 
    try { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $countComments = $stmt->rowCount();
        global $countComments;
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) { die();
    }
}
```

I then am trying to use

```
$countComments
```

But no luck.

The code itself works when not in the function.

Comment: That's an *awful* way to do this. Just return the value and assign it to a variable. That's the kind of code that makes the next guy working on it violent.

Comment: Dont want that to happen... can i ask why its awful? whats the right way to do it? how do you mean just return the value?

Comment: Functions are built to provide an easy way to produce an output based on input and an algorythm. What you're doing isn't strictly correct because the function is instead modifying a global variable. Usually you should just use "  return $countComments;  " and call the function outside like " $myvar = select_ALL_Comments_Fom_ID($myid);  ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global $idNew` affects the variable lookup just when it's executed - not before. E.g. take a look at

```
<?php
$a = 9;
foo();

function foo() {
    $a = 5; // this sets the value for the variable in the local lookup table
    echo $a, "\r\n"; // scope of $a is still local -> 5
    global $a; // now the lookup for "a" is switched to the global scope
    echo $a, "\r\n";  // $a "points" to the global value -> 9
}
```

the output is

```
5
9
```

and in your case

```
function select_All_Comments_From_ID($buildID){
    $idNew = $buildID;
        global $idNew
}
```

the function writes the value to its local $idNew and then the lookup for `idNew` is switched to the global scope - but that doesn't copy the local value to the global scope; just the lookup has been changed.

---

Anyway as pointed out before you really should return the values instead of setting them globally. And if all you're interested in is the number of (matching) records in a table - not the payload data of the records - use a `SELECT Count(...)` query. Otherwise your script transfers all the data from the database server into the memory space of your php instance  ...for nothing but heating up the cpu and memory.

```
function select_All_Comments_From_ID($buildID){
    $query = " SELECT Count(*) as c FROM comments WHERE buildID = :buildID"; 
    $query_params = array(':buildID' => $buildID); 
    try { 
       // what's $db here ?
       // neither has it been passed to the function nor is it fetched from the global scope
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        return $row['c'];
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) { 
      // using die(...) is crude, even more so without any notice/text
      die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$countComments = $stmt->rowCount();
global $countComments;
```

in

```
$GLOBALS['countComments'] = $stmt->rowCount();
```

By the way, the comment is right, that's an awful solution, you should really change it.

Comment: OP is asking why "$idNew" aka $countComments will show "0 / nothing". What I provided is the correct syntax to assign a global variable its value.

Comment: I tried that first, but was issued with this: Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `';''

Comment: @user2921557 sorry I just messed up (drowsiness can be awful), updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define $countComments at outside of the function even if it defined as a **global** at inside of function.

Example :

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    global $a, $b;

    $b = $a + $b;
} 

Sum();
echo $b;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a value from your function, instead of using a Global, like this:

```
function select_All_Comments_From_ID($buildID){
    $query = " SELECT * FROM comments WHERE buildID = :buildID"; 
    $query_params = array(':buildID' => $buildID); 
    try { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute($query_params);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $countComments = $stmt->rowCount();
        return $countComments; //sends the value back outside the scope of the function
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) { die(); }
}
```

When you call the function, you need a variable to catch the return value, like this:

```
$buildID = 5;
$countComments = select_All_Comments_From_ID($buildID);
echo $countComments;
```